# Mac Mini white screen - no recovery / no os installed

Tags: macos, bootcamp, recovery

I wiped (all partitions) a MacMini without knowing it was running bootcamp. This caused it to go to a Windows screen that said "no bootable device" when I used cmd R during boot to select a DVD or USB drive to boot from.

I got rid of that error with an NVRAM reset but...

Now, if I insert a Yosemite install DVD and use cmd during startup to select the DV, I hear the DVD spinning and the Mac sits at a white screen.

I created a Yosemite USB installer, it does the same thing as the DVD.

I also created a Lion Recovery USB, it does the same thing, white screen.

What else can I do to install OSX or to install a recovery partition to install OSX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try a SMC/NVRAM reset while no device is plugged in. If that doesn't work, then connect it to another Mac and use Target Disk Mode to reinstall OS X